# How do I use an edit viewmodel in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, mvvm

I have been struggling with this for some time. I have a model and an edit view model so I can allow the user to both see the image that was uploaded before and upload a replacement. Everything works fine until I get to the `db.Entry` portion. The error is:

> The entity type EditCardViewModel is not part of the model for the current context.

If I try to add `EditCardViewModel` to the `DbContext`, it wants a key and a table, which isn't going to happen. The ViewModel is just a way to pass data. How do I tell it to use the Cards context when saving from this ViewModel?

Controller Edit Get:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{

    Card card = db.Cards.Find(id);
    ViewData["Abilities"] = card.CardAbilities.Select(a => a.AbilityID);

    if (card == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    var editview = new EditCardViewModel(card);
    {
    } 
    return View(editview);
}
```

Controller Edit Post:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EditCardViewModel card) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if(card.ImageUpload != null)
        {
            string savedFileName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Images");
            savedFileName = Path.Combine(savedFileName, Path.GetFileName(card.ImageUpload.FileName));
            card.ImageUpload.SaveAs(savedFileName);
            card.Cards.ImageUrl = "\\Images\\" + Path.GetFileName(card.ImageUpload.FileName);
        }
        db.Entry(card).State = EntityState.Modified; //ERROR - Entity Type is not part of context
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Edit ViewModel:

```
public class EditCardViewModel
{
    public Card Cards { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageUpload { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Abilities { get; set; }
    public int[] SelectedAbilities { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Rarities { get; set; }
    public int SelectedRarities { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MainTypes { get; set; }
    public int SelectedMainTypes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SubTypes { get; set; }
    public int SelectedSubTypes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectList> CardSets { get; set; }
    public int SelectedCardSets { get; set; }
    public Rarity Rarity { get; set; }
    public MainType MainType { get; set; }
    public SubType SubType { get; set; }
    public CardSet CardSet { get; set; }

    public EditCardViewModel() { } //NEEDED OR PARAMETERLESS CONSTRUCTOR ERROR
    public EditCardViewModel(Card card) //NEEDED OR CANNOT PASS CARD MODEL
    {
        Cards = card;
    }

}
```

Comment: Erm...why don't you just call `db.Entry(card.Cards).State = EntityState.Modified;` instead?

Comment: mmm I think that you don't need a edit viewmodel. You can chage the state of the entity.

Comment: The edit viewmodel is the only way I have found that I can save an image (URL to database and actual image to server). Altering the db.Entry to use card.Cards works but now I have an error about foreign key constraints :(

Comment: Had to pass a view variables that I didn't have set up. Now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your view model is not recognised by Entity Framework - it has no idea that `EditCardViewModel` is meant to be a representation of a `Card`. It's a bit unclear from your view model exactly what you are doing with it but you either need to create a new `Card` object and use that:

```
var newCard = new Card
{
    Id = card.Id //for example
};
```

Or possibly use the `Cards` property of your view model as that is of the correct type.